# Can this loop in the Arithmetic Numbers Calculation Problem be parallelised?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I suppose that `divisor_count` and `divisor_sum` variables could be reduction variables for threads in the potential parallelisation of the outer loop. I am just a bit confused if that parallelisation is actually possible, because `n` is changing in the inner loop, so does that mean that iterations of the outer loop are dependent on each other and that parallelisation isn't possible for that reason?

```
unsigned int divisor_count = 1;
unsigned int divisor_sum = 1;
unsigned int power;
for (unsigned int p = 3; p * p <= n; p += 2)
{
    unsigned int count = 1, sum = 1;
    for (power = p; n % p == 0; power *= p, n /= p)
    {
        ++count;
        sum += power;
    }
    divisor_count *= count;
    divisor_sum *= sum;
}
```

Comment: Make the outer loop over prime numbers, and give each iteration a *copy* of `n`. As it is, no, this can not be parallelized.

Comment: Could you please modify the code and paste it here, I am not sure I have understood you. Thank you for the quick response! Also, am I correct, is the reason for the impossibility of parallelisation the data dependency between iterations because of the changing n?

Comment: Basically yes, see [Canonical Loop Form](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu40.html). The range of a loop needs to be completely determined at the start for `parallel for`.

Comment: @paleonix : the outer loop is well formed for OpenMP. the problem is the data dependence from dividing out the factors of `n`. But if each `p` value gets its own copy of `n` through `firstprivate` it all works out. I think.

Comment: @PavleŠarenac Why don't you start writing OpenMP directives, and then I may give suggestions.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout `p * p <= n` clearly isn't allowed as a *test-expr* according to the standard. I don't know if some implementations still accept it in this case, but that would be an extension to the standard.

Comment: @paleonix Good point. The number of iterations is determined but the exact formulatiaon needs improving.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but surely the divisor_count and divisor_sum accumulations should be +=, not *= ?

Comment: @PavleŠarenac `unsigned int p = 3; p * p <= n; p += 2` risk overflow for large prime `n`.  Use `unsigned int p = 3; p <= n/p; p += 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean "Arithmetic Numbers" in the sense of [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_number), your whole computation looks dubious to me.

Here is a simple Python code that checks whether a number is arithmetic. Conversion to C/C++ and parallelisation should be trivial.

```
import math

def isArithmetic(n):
    divisorSum = 1+n
    divisorCount = 2
    ub = math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))

    # Handle the square case outside the loop, since
    # the square root only counts as one factor.
    if (ub*ub == n):
        divisorSum += ub
        divisorCount += 1
    # Find all the other pairs of factors
    for i in range(2,ub):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            divisorSum += i + n/i
            divisorCount += 2

    return (divisorSum % divisorCount) == 0

arithmeticNumbers = [i for i in range(1,50) if isArithmetic(i)]

print (arithmeticNumbers)
```

That gives the same set as the article. I doubt that you'll get much performance increase, though, since the work in the loop is rather small.

(I've left the rest for you, since I don't want to do all of your homework for you :-)).